# Accessing an 'f0_' field

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, alias, common-table-expression

I have created a common table expression with a list of dates within a range using the following SQL code in BigQuery:

```
WITH    calendar AS(
        SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
        )
```

If I were to run that as a query without the 'WITH' clause, the query would return a single column called 'f0_' (you should be able to reproduce this result yourself).

Now, the problem I'm having is that when I attempt to access that column in a separate SELECT statement, the name 'f0_' is not recognised. ("Unrecognized name: f0_")

```
WITH    calendar AS(
        SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
        )

SELECT  f0_
FROM    calendar
```

Of course, that query in itself is pointless, as I could just run the first SELECT statement without the WITH clause and not need the second SELECT statement. I get that. The end result I'm after is a little more complex though, and the logic above should be sufficient to explain the problem I'm having. Basically, if the SELECT statement inside that common table expression returns a column called 'f0_' when I run it as a standalone query, why does my second SELECT statement return an error when it's referencing a common table expression that seems like it should return a column called 'f0_'.

I assume it's something along the lines of 'f0_' not being a real name - it's just something that gets assigned in the absence of any specified name, or maybe the naming works differently when you run it as a common table expression rather than a simple SELECT statement. Is there a way I can alias the unnested date array within my common table expression so that I can access it in the second part of my query? Or some other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an alias:

```
WITH calendar AS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as dt
)
SELECT dt
FROM  calendar
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. Turns out my brackets were in the wrong place. Works now; thanks